# Launch python commands in parallel using shell

Tags: python, shell, parallel-processing, gnu-parallel

I have a command in python this way:

```
Python my_prog in1.fa ins.fa out1.fa
Python my_prog in2.fa ins.fa out2.fa
Python my_prog in3.fa ins.fa out3.fa
```

I used the parallel command of GNU parallel and I assemble the files in1.fa, in2.fa and in3.fa in the one file IN.fa.
My problem is I do not know how to put another agument or more in the parallel command.
here is my command:

```
cat IN.fa | parallel -j 20 --cat --pipe --block 3M --recstart '>' time python my_prog.py
```

How can I make several arguments in the command Parallel please?

Answer (score 1):

Let us assume that `my_prog` can read from stdin and send output to stdout and that it takes a single argument (`ins.fa`):

```
parallel --pipepart -a in.fa --block 3M Python my_prog ins.fa > out.fa
```

If `my_prog` cannot read from stdin, but from a named pipe (fifo) this will work:

```
parallel --fifo --pipepart -a in.fa Python my_prog {} ins.fa > out.fa
```

If `my_prog` cannot read from a fifo, but only an actual file, this will work:

```
parallel --cat --pipepart -a in.fa Python my_prog {} ins.fa > out.fa
```

If `my_prog` cannot output to stdout, but can output to a fifo you can often use:

```
parallel --cat --pipepart -a in.fa Python my_prog {} ins.fa {#}.out /dev/stdout  > out.fa
```

Or:

```
parallel --cat --pipepart -a in.fa Python my_prog {} ins.fa {#}.out '>(cat)' > out.fa
```

If `my_prog` cannot output to a fifo, you need to have it output to a uniquely named file, which you can then `cat` and remove. Here we use the sequence number to make a unique file.

```
parallel --cat --pipepart -a in.fa Python my_prog {} ins.fa {#}.out '; cat {#}.out; rm {#}.out'  > out.fa
```

You really should consider walking through the tutorial. It will answer this and *so* many other questions: man parallel_tutorial

Comment: no! it's not my question. I want to partition my file IN.fa into subfiles in block 3M since they compare with ins.fa and each time gives me a result in a separate file.